# Power BI paginated report now showing all the records in web layout

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

We've converted several SSRS reports to Power BI paginated reports.  There are a handful of Power BI paginated reports that have given us issues.

Our process is to download the SSRS report, open it with Power BI Report Builder, update the credentials, then run the report to verify it works properly in Power BI Report Builder, after that we publish the report.

Once published, we only see 5 records in the Web Layout view.  If we switch over to the Page Layout view we see them all.

Is there some setting that limits the number of records to display in Web Layout view?